# Is there an open-source Flurry alternative?

Tags: ios, flurry

I don't want to use Flurry, nor Localitics, because I'd like to integrate the reporting system with my own server.

Is there a library, that would do the same thing as flurry, but that would send the logs to my own server?

Comment: how is this unconstructive? I didn't ask for the best tool for the task, but for a very concrete thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Localystics client is open-source, so in theory you could adapt it to your needs, but you'd need to handle the server-side yourself.

http://wiki.localytics.com/doku.php?id=open_source_information

I don't know of a comparable open-source client-and-server solution.

Comment: You're right. I found it out after asking the question.

Comment: User 'brucenan' commented: "Cobub razor is what you want. client and server sides are both open source." http://www.github.com/cobub/razor

Comment: wow, cobub razor looks quite nice. thanks

Comment: @SvenViking Are you sure it's open source!?